# Replace a set of strings with an other using regexp

Tags: c#, regex

I have a rather nasty string on form:

```
<aa>b</aa><ccc>ddd</ccc>
```

and i'd like all the tags to be exchanged for `<td>` so we'll see this:

```
<td>b</td><td>ddd</td>
```

How can i do that in C#? I'm guessing regexp but it's been a while ago so i'll need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startTag = new Regex(@"\<(?<tag>\w+)\s*\>");
var endTag = new Regex(@"\<\/\w+\>");
var result = startTag.Replace("<aa>b</aa><ccc>ddd</ccc>", "<td class=\"${tag}\">");
result = endTag.Replace(result,"</td>");
```

Regex Substitutions on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#Named

Comment: And if i wish the output to be like this? <td class='aa'>b</td><td class='ccc'>ddd</td>? How hard is this?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I changed my answer to accommodate your request. XML is easier than RegEx in this case, as Charlie suggests.  :)

Comment: I have changed my code to convert the tag name to class name.

Comment: Oh, the main point of this approach is to refresh my regex skills to dazzle a co-worker. But i agree XML is easier than regex. In fact {put in almost anything} is probably easier than regex. I admire people fluent in it...

Answer (score 0):

I lost my regex-fu black belt a long time ago to some finite automaton from the Kessel system.

It looks like you are trying to massage some XML-like structures.  Is there a chance that there could be CDATA records contained in the element values?  If so, the regex required to *not* do the replacement inside the CDATA sections is likely way above my pay grade.  Otherwise, @Charlie seems to have a great answer!

If CDATA records containing internal tags may be present, you may be able to consume the string as XML and manipulate it that way.  Based on your example, I wrapped the string fragment in a single root element in order to parse it into an XElement, and then unwrapped it after renaming all the nodes.  Not as clever as some 7-th dan regex-fu master, I'm sure, but might help you out.

**EDIT**: based on wanting the output string to be like this:  `<td class='aa'>b</td><td class='ccc'>ddd</td>`, then XML processing is definitely the way to go, IMHO.

```
var s = @"<aa>b</aa><ccc>ddd</ccc>";

var prefix = "<wrapper>";
var suffix = "</wrapper>";
var wrapped = prefix + s + suffix;

var wrapper = XElement.Parse(wrapped);
foreach (var e in wrapper.Descendants())
{
    e.Add(new XAttribute("class", e.Name));
    e.Name = "td";
}

wrapped = wrapper.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

// extract the resulting string from the root element
var result = wrapped.Substring(prefix.Length, wrapped.Length - (prefix.Length + suffix.Length));

Console.WriteLine(result);  // --> "<td class=\"aa\">b</td><td class=\"ccc\">ddd</td>"
```

This produces `<td class="aa">b</td><td class="ccc">ddd</td>`

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get XElement to produce single quotes instead of double quotes for attribute values.  However, both are valid XML, so perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: No CDATA. I'm just refreshing my regex skills. A programmer had a problem. And he said: "i know! i'll use RegEx!". Now he has two problems...   :)